# Recommended number of threads in NioEventLoopGroup()

Tags: netty

Is there some guidance regarding how many worker threads should I create in a netty application? By default, netty creates 2 * number of processors threads, but provides user with flexibility to create more threads. My question is two fold:

(i) What is the rationale for creating "2 * number of processors" threads by default?

(ii) In what situation should I override this default??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to it.

It all depends
* what else is running on the server

- how many concurrent connections
- what handlers are in the pipeline
- are the threads busy
- ...

So you will need to check with for example a profiler to find the optimal setting for your app.